# Why doesn't RestController pick up request after AuthenticationFilter has finished

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a working Spring Boot with Spring Security. Everything mostly works. What I'm not understanding is why the RestController never fires following the filter authorizing the request.

In other words, I have a rest controller set up to accept POST requests from /foo/bar and I have an AuthenticationFilter set up to first verify the users credentials before performing what the user requested.

Given that my RestController never fires, I've had to implement my code in the Success Handler, but my code belongs in the Controller instead.

I've attempted to debug this by stepping through Spring Security code, but nothing appears to suggest it would skip my RestController.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("foo")
public class FooController {

  @PostMapping("bar") // this never executes
  public ResponseEntity<FooResponse> foobar(@RequestBody Credentials creds) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new FooResponse("baz"), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilter() throws Exception {

    AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl());
    return filter;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(accountService)
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }    

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
      .cors()
      .and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/foo/bar").permitAll()
      .and()
      .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(properties, authenticationManager(), tokenService)
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);              
    }

}
```

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {  

  public AuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/foo/bar"); 
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Credentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Credentials.class);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                          creds.getUsername(),
                          creds.getPassword(),
                          new ArrayList<>())
                    );      
  }
}
```

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // do nothing and prevent redirect to /login, /logout, etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a / before both foo and bar in the controller request mapping?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed. Also if I remove the AuthenticationFilter (and move the logic from attemptAuthentication() into the Controller), then everything fires as I'd expect it, but then that defeats the purpose of a filter checking my auth credentials before I do my real work in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  http.cors(). Have you configured it elsewhere? If not, it probably considers you are not authenticated. Check this link out: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html

I would suggest you to remove it if you are not going to use it

Also you have here an example of an easy security configuration: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

From my point of view, removing cors() should fix your problem (or configuring it the right way :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it still does not appear to route to my request to the RestController following authenticating. To clarify, it does authenticate: 
```AuthenticationFilter: Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder...```
```AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl : Overriding default authentication success handler.```
```ExceptionTranslationFilter: Chain processed normally
HstsHeaderWriter: Not injecting HSTS header...```
```SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed```